NextJS React project, can't start localhost "Compiled /_not-found"
I'm developing a React project using NextJS, and until a couple of days ago, everything was working perfectly. Today, when I tried to run the application on localhost, I encountered a '404 This page could not be found' error. This error appeared despite the fact that I haven’t made any changes since it was last running successfully. I'm uncertain what could have caused this issue to appear suddenly, and I'm looking for help on identifying the problem.
I've tried clearing the cache and restarting the development server, but the issue persists.
Тhe only change I can notice is that after running the "npm run dev" command, a file named "_not-found" is compiled.
This is what happens when i try to run npm run dev :
  ▲ Next.js 14.2.16
  - Local:        http://localhost:3000

 ✓ Starting...
 ✓ Ready in 2.5s
 ○ Compiling /_not-found ...
 ✓ Compiled /_not-found in 2.2s (463 modules)
 GET / 404 in 2486ms

